# How to share my customized elementary OS with my friends

Tags: release-freya, settings

After I installed elementary OS, I made some wonderful customization and my friend like it very much. How can I share my OS with my friends?

I don't wish to do it for every friend manually all over again. I am assuming there is a way to package my OS into a file or similar. Then I can share this file with my friends and they can import it into their laptop easily. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Yuhua
Best regards

Comment: Hi Yuhua, if one of these answers solved your issue, remember to mark it with the checkmark so it'll be promoted accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You could write a bash script containing all the commands that you used to get your OS the way you want it. You could then share that script with friends, and they could run that script on their copy of elementary to get your changes. (If you did things in the GUI, you may need to find command line equivalents of what you did.)

I'd recommend testing this script in a virtual machine with a fresh copy of elementary OS before giving the script to your friends! :)

What you're looking to do is a little like building your own Linux distro. That's probably way overkill for what you want to do here, but if you're interested, [this article](https://www.linuxvoice.com/build-your-own-linux-distro/) explains how to get started.

Answer (score 2):

Ryan's solution is very good. UCK is a good tool, but from my experience it can be a bit buggy sometimes.

Here's another tutorial on how to customize your own distro manually.

https://nathanpfry.com/how-to-customize-an-ubuntu-installation-disc/

Answer (score 0):

Use Systemback to create your system iso image.
See here: http://www.istitutomajorana.it/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2309&Itemid=33